# Submitting iPhone and iPad apps to the store with the same names

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

Can I submit two builds, one for iPhone and the other for iPad, to the App Store under the same name? My iPhone app is already in the App Store, named "xxx", and I developed another, built for iPad. Can I submit this build to the App Store, with the same "xxx" name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can, we've done it with our app when the iPad got released.

You will have to modify your plist to start with different xib/nib files depending on the device type - then it's up to your app to determine if it's in iPad mode or iPhone.

There is no way to have two separate apps under the same name / app id, but going from iPhone only to a universal app is not a problem at all.

Here is a link to a document that introduces universal apps (Apple docs have much more details though):
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf